# Finding peaks across multiple time series

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find the peak value across multiple time series concurrently, like the following. However to make this a little more complicated, I may have 20k+ entities with 200 data points each, so performance is important.

I only require the peak achieved across all entities. So for clarification, let's say my entities are stores and my value is total sales per day, and I want to find out which day was the peak sales day across all 20k stores.

Sample data

```
Date Time    Entity Value
01/01/1900  A   8
01/01/1900  B   6
01/01/1900  C   9
02/01/1900  A   4
02/01/1900  B   3
02/01/1900  C   6
03/01/1900  A   7
03/01/1900  B   8
03/01/1900  C   9
04/01/1900  A   1
04/01/1900  B   2
04/01/1900  C   5
```

OUTPUT

```
Date Time   A   B   C   Total
01/01/1900  8   6   9   23
02/01/1900  4   3   6   13
03/01/1900  7   8   9   24
04/01/1900  1   2   5   8
```

However this output is not important, I simple require the peak DateTime and total.

```
Date Time   Total
03/01/1900  24
```

Comment: Please do not use screenshots as we, answerers, cannot copy-paste them.

Comment: What do you mean "peak achieved across all entities"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff let's say my entities are stores and my value is sales per day, I want to find out are peak sales day across all our stores ( entities )

Comment: @garyamorris, is the OUTPUT correct in your question? My apologies if not. I'm the one who edited it.

Comment: @garyamorris, You are saying that you have 20K entities. Looking at your sample Output... Do you really want the result set to have 20K columns (plus one for `datetime` and one for `Total`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just the date of the maximum sum, then simple `GROUP BY` would be enough.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cc27/2/0)

```
SELECT TOP(1)
    dt
    ,SUM(Value) AS Total
FROM T
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

**Result**

```
dt          Total
1900-01-03  24
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot, I really struggled with this one and I'm especially disappointed that with such a simplistic answer, I didn't come up with it myself. Great work, just tested it with 20k entities and 2500 data points and it only took 4 seconds. Smashed my requirements.

Comment: @garyamorris, No problem, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

*here solution using dynamic query*

```
-- create temp table for data sample
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #test
CREATE TABLE #test
    (
      [Date Time] DATE ,
      Entity VARCHAR(1) ,
      VALUE INT
    )

INSERT  INTO #test
        ( [Date Time], Entity, VALUE )
VALUES  ( '1900-01-01', 'A', 4 ),
        ( '1900-01-01', 'B', 6 ),
        ( '1900-01-01', 'C', 9 ),
        ( '1900-01-02', 'A', 4 ),
        ( '1900-01-02', 'B', 3 ),
        ( '1900-01-02', 'C', 6 ),
        ( '1900-01-03', 'A', 7 ),
        ( '1900-01-03', 'B', 8 ),
        ( '1900-01-03', 'C', 9 ),
        ( '1900-01-04', 'A', 1 ),
        ( '1900-01-04', 'B', 2 ),
        ( '1900-01-04', 'C', 5 )

--final query

DECLARE @String AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @String = SUBSTRING(( SELECT    ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Entity) + ']'
                          FROM      ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                                Entity
                                      FROM      #test
                                    ) AS t
                          ORDER BY  Entity
                        FOR
                          XML PATH('')
                        ), 2, 1000)

SET @String = 'SELECT *, ' + REPLACE(@String, ',', '+') + ' AS Total '
    + 'FROM (SELECT * FROM #test AS [T] PIVOT ( MAX(T.VALUE) FOR [T].[Entity] IN ('
    + @String + ') ) AS P) AS T'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @String
```

***test is here*** [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83c31/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Datetime,A,B,C,Total=SUM([A]+[B]+[C])
FROM Table
PIVOT
(SUM(value)  FOR entity in ([A],[B],[C]))  AS P
GROUP BY Datetime,A,B,C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block :

`select t.date_time
      ,sum(t.value) as value
  from test t
 group by t.date_time
 order by t.date_time`

It gives this output :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/haU02.png